If $X^TX\beta=X^TY$, then $X\beta$ is independent of $\beta$
This question is motivated by linear statistical inference, and more specifically, the normal equation for a least squares estimate and estimable functions. But it boils down to pure linear algebra.
Let $X$ be any $n\times m$ matrix, $Y$ a $n\times 1$ vector. Given that $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are solutions to the normal equation, i.e. $X^TX\beta_i=X^TY$, I want to show that $X\beta_1=X\beta_2$. Now, if $X$ has full column rank, this is trivial since then $X^TX$ is invertible and therefore $\beta_1=\beta_2$. For the more general case, however, I was only able to prove it by considering a singular value decomposition of $X$. I was wondering if there is a more straightforward proof of this fact which doesn't require invoking the hammer that is SVDs. Does anyone know of a simpler proof?

$X\beta = PY$, the orthogonal projection of $Y$ onto $Range(X)$. Since orthogonal projections onto closed convex sets are unique, this is independent of $\beta$.

From the normal equation,
$$X^\top X (\beta_1 - \beta_2) = X^\top X \beta_1 - X^\top X \beta_2 = X^\top Y - X^\top Y = 0.$$
Thus,
$$\|X(\beta_1 - \beta_2)\|^2 = (\beta_1 - \beta_2)^\top X^\top X (\beta_1 - \beta_2) = 0,$$
so $X\beta_1 = X\beta_2$.

This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

I wonder if $ X^\top X \beta_1 - X^\top X \beta_2=0\implies X^\top (X \beta_1- X \beta_2)=0\implies X\beta_1 = X\beta_2$?

@MathArt: If they both satisfy the normal equations, then the resulting regression lines have to be the same so yes, your claim is true.
